# How to use Tapku Calendar Framework with NSFetchRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nscalendar

I'm trying to get the Tapku Calendar Library working with core data in my app.  I have got the calendar setup but what I am trying to do now is get the dot markers to display for dates which are saved in my core data.

I am trying to follow this example [(http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers](http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers)) but I'm stuck when mixing it with core data.

The method I need to work with is:

```
- (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {    
    NSLog(@"calendarMonthView marksFromDate toDate");   
    NSLog(@"Make sure to update 'data' variable to pull from CoreData, website, User Defaults, or some other source.");
    // When testing initially you will have to update the dates in this array so they are visible at the
    // time frame you are testing the code.
    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-12-01 00:00:00 +0000", nil]; 


    // Initialise empty marks array, this will be populated with TRUE/FALSE in order for each day a marker should be placed on.
    NSMutableArray *marks = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Initialise calendar to current type and set the timezone to never have daylight saving
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    // Construct DateComponents based on startDate so the iterating date can be created.
    // Its massively important to do this assigning via the NSCalendar and NSDateComponents because of daylight saving has been removed 
    // with the timezone that was set above. If you just used "startDate" directly (ie, NSDate *date = startDate;) as the first 
    // iterating date then times would go up and down based on daylight savings.
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | 
                                                    NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) 
                                          fromDate:startDate];
    NSDate *d = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

    // Init offset components to increment days in the loop by one each time
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setDay:1];    


    // for each date between start date and end date check if they exist in the data array
    while (YES) {
        // Is the date beyond the last date? If so, exit the loop.
        // NSOrderedDescending = the left value is greater than the right
        if ([d compare:lastDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            break;
        }

        // If the date is in the data array, add it to the marks array, else don't
        if ([data containsObject:[d description]]) {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        } else {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        }

        // Increment day using offset components (ie, 1 day in this instance)
        d = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:d options:0];
    }

    [offsetComponents release];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:marks];
}
```

Comment: How can I make the calendar marks work with the fetch from my core data?

Answer (score 0):

there is a class like TKCalendarMonthView check that which will have dots to be displayed depending upon the array which you will give from core data. the array from your core data which will be a date will compared with dates for the particular month which you show in calendar if both dates matches then BOOL will return as it will marked with "."..

Comment: I'm looking at `TKCalendarMonthView` class but don't really see any place to enter that fetch I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using this method:

```
     - (void) generateDataForStartDate:(NSDate*)start endDate:(NSDate*)end
        {

                 //just check the condition according to you...It;s your logic that would work
                 if([datestring isEqualToString:strtemp])
                    {
                        Done=YES;
                        [dataDictionary setObject:str forKey:d];//USed to show the data
                        [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; // This array would store the place where you need to set the Dot in Calender
                        j=1;
                    }
        // This is the logic for not setting the DOT
         if(j==0){
            [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
                }

        TKDateInformation info = [d dateInformation];
        info.day++;
        Done=NO;
        d = [NSDate dateFromDateInformation:info];
        if([d compare:end]==NSOrderedDescending) break;


        }
```

Hope that would solve your problem....else you could so it by your own just setting up the [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]; to yes/no based on your condition.

Comment: Thanks AJ, I am posting the code that the sample app used to populate the dots in their calendar.  Do you know how to modify your code or just use the fetch I posted originally?

Comment: Over here I assume that you already have the data in your array based on which you want to put the dots. You just need to play with this line :[dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]; either to set the dot or not. Still you have some confusion let me no.

Comment: The fetch I have in question can be set to an array.  that array will then have the dates for which I want a dot to be displayed.  So do I still need your code, or is there an easier way to put the 2 togheter?

Comment: You will need the help from my code...since based on dates I have set the dot for respective dates.So you need to check whether on that day there is any record if yes then [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; else   [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];. And at last need to have the all 5 lines from my code ;)

Comment: Thanks Ajay, I updated question with the full method the sample app uses for their marks.  Can you show me just how to incorporate my data from the fetch instead of theirs?